# Update query failed '0' rows affected

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to run this query but the query keeps giving up on me:

```
Update StockInvoiceInfo set Quantity = Quantity - 2  where p_id = 5 AND ProductDate = convert(Cast('31-5-2015' as datetime)) ;
```

After Running this code it returns an error below:

> Incorrect syntax near '31-5-2015'

The datatype of the `ProductDate` column is`Date`. I am using `Sql Server 2012`.

Comment: If `ProductDate` is Date then can compare using an agnostic string format like '2015-05-31'. No need for cast or convert ? Unless ProductDate is actually a DateTime, and you want to update all rows on the same day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is compare a Sql Date, then just use an agnostic format like `'20150531'` or easier to read `'2015-05-31'`. No need for casts or convert at all, i.e.

```
WHERE ... AND ProductDate = '2015-05-31'
```

However, if `ProductDate` isn't a date, but one of the `*DATETIME*` data types, and you are looking to update any time on the same day, then I believe you are looking for something like:

```
Update StockInvoiceInfo 
set Quantity = Quantity - 2  
where 
  p_id = 5 
  AND CAST(ProductDate AS DATE) = '2015-05-31';
```

However, the performance will be lousy as the clause isn't likely to be SARGable. You're better off simply doing:

```
AND ProductDate >= '2015-05-31' AND ProductDate < '2015-06-01';
```

(Resist the temptation to use between, or hacks like ':23:59:59' as there will be data corner cases which will bite you)

Comment: @StuartLV can you elaborate me upon the between and the hacks

Comment: I mean don't do #1 `AND ProductDate BETWEEN '2015-05-31' AND '2015-06-01'` as this will include `2015-06-01` and #2 `BETWEEN '2015-05-31' AND '2015-05-31 23:59:59'` as this still leaves room for rounding error in the second before midnight. Can you just confirm, you needed to cast `ProductDate` to date only?

Comment: Actually I am deducting the quantity on the basis of Product Stock date there is nothing like comparing two dates. i wanted to make my update query work in dynamic environment on app (Desktop APP)
which deducts the quantity on the basis of product id and date

Answer (score 3):

You have used `Convert` functions but didn't supplied it with parameters. Also there is no need for this function here. Also take care of date format. I have changed it to standard format:

```
Update StockInvoiceInfo set Quantity = Quantity - 2  
where p_id = 5 AND ProductDate = Cast('2015-05-31' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `CAST('5-31-2015' as DATETIME)`

Answer (score 0):

with the above update statement you started convert but with incomplete syntax 
here the convert syntax

```
  Update StockInvoiceInfo 
set Quantity = Quantity - 2  
where p_id = 5
 AND ProductDate = convert(datetime,Cast('31-5-2015' as varchar),103) ;
```

Comment: Agreed with your answer and everyone who have helped me ..
but one last doubt and we can close the conversation

`   string up1 = " Update StockInvoiceInfo set Quantity = Quantity - '" + item["Column 2"].ToString() + "'  where p_id = '" + item["Column 0"].ToString()  + "' AND ProductDate = '" +  DateTime.Parse(item["Column 5"].ToString())  + "' " `

is this right

Comment: what is this @someshtripathi you are trying to do in dynamic query or it is front end code

Comment: yes it is the front end code sorry couldn't format it